# Application of Neyman Pearson lemma.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let X be a random variable having a probability density function $f \in (f_o,f_1)$,  where

$f_0(x) = \biggl(1 \ \  \ \ if \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1\,, \ 0  \ otherwise\biggr )$

and

$f_1(x) = \biggl(\dfrac{1}{2} \ \  \ \ if \ \ 0\leq x \leq 2\,, \ 0  \ otherwise\biggr )$

For testing the null hypothesis $H_0:f=f_0$ against $H_1:f=f_1$ based on a single observation on $X$, the power of the most powerful test of size $\alpha = 0.05$ equals ?

My inpuit : I applied NP lemma.
Since we have a single observation. Test is to reject $H_0$
if 
$Pr$$\left\{\dfrac{f_1}{f_0}\geq K
\right\}$ = $.05$

I am having problem in finding the critical region. I divided these densities and i got  $\dfrac{f_1}{f_0} = \dfrac{1}{2}  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ 0\leq x \leq 1\ $

$\dfrac{1}{2} \geq K$

What do i depict from it ?

Comment: How about finding _a_ most powerful test of size $\alpha = 0.05.$

Comment: Meaning? I am having problem in finding critical region.

Comment: You have two intervals to consider $(0,1)$ and $(1,2).$ You have some arbitrary choices to make in order to have a test of size $\alpha$ The criterion involves $\ge K$ not $> K.$ Use _part_ of an interval.

Comment: Can i show you 4 options i had in this question. Could you please give a try coz i tried it tons of time.

Comment: If you reject _just_ for $x$ in the interval $(1,2),$ then what is $\alpha$ and what is the power?

Comment: This was the question i have no idea what are you saying i am very new to this concept. i just know how to apply it. I need knowledge on it. Please explain whatever you are saying. http://prntscr.com/hyf2ok 
This was the question. Just tell me how to solve this with the help of neyman pearson lemma sir.

Comment: If you try to answer my last question, you might learn something. What if the rejection region were $(.95, 2)$ an interval of length 1.05 and with what probability under $f_1?$

Comment: you said two intervals 0 to 1 and 1 to 2 but 2nd interval is 0 to 2 sir.

Comment: Those are the supports of the two PDFs. I'm talking about Acc and Rej regions.

Comment: With the last dumb reply i did you can see how much i know this stuff can you help me a little bit explaining things please.

Comment: In two previous comments I have essentially (a) given you the right answer and (b) given you a rationale for it. // Sorry, but that is as close to working this problem for you as I am willing to get. // I suggest you re-read the N-P lemma and look at a couple of examples of it's application that are a little more trivial than this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Lambda(x) = \frac{f_0(x)}{f_1(x)}$ and reject if $\Lambda(x) < \tau$. Note that because the likelihood ratio has the [Monotone Likelihood Ratio Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio) we can instead reject if $x>\tau'$.

Letting $\phi(x) = I_{x>.95}$ be our test. We can see that $\alpha = E_0[\phi(x)] = P_0[X>.95] = .05$.

To get the power of the test: $E_{1}[\phi(x)] = P_1[X>.95] = \frac{1}{2}[2-.95] = \frac{21}{40}$.

Because the test was constructed using the Neyman-Pearson Lemma, and because there is only one parameter in the alternative set, it is a UMP test.

Comment: So today is the day I understood this topic. I was weak in Stas. inference that's why didn't understand a thing last year. I just wanted to say thanks. I understood your answer now. Last year it went over my head.